# Google Analytics (Universal): Regex Filter on report for multiple pages

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, universal-analytics, regex

I'm setting up an Analytics report and want the data from two pages combined. I don't want the data from any of the subpages or parent pages included.

Say that the pages are [Trier Blog](https://www.uni-trier.de/international/international-in-trier/fit-fuers-studium/studienbruecke/blog-der-studienbruecke) and [Wilkommenskultur](https://www.uni-trier.de/international/international-in-trier/fit-fuers-studium/studienbruecke/blog-der-studienbruecke/hani-abo-kheir)

I can get the data for each page separately using the Page filter and Exact. If I try to combine the pages using an additional Page filter and Exact followed by the subdomain, the report stops returning any data.

If I switch to Regex and do the following, will I get back just the data for the two pages, or will it also return data for other pages sharing the **blog-der-studienbruecke** sub-domain?

`/international/international-in-trier/fit-fuers-studium/studienbruecke/blog-der-studienbruecke|/international/international-in-trier/fit-fuers-studium/studienbruecke/blog-der-studienbruecke/hani-abo-kheir`

Comment: I see a _possible_ error in the regex: `.../blog-der-studienbruecke|international/international-in-trier/fit-fuers-studium/...` Shouldn't it be `.../blog-der-studienbruecke|/international/international-in-trier/fit-fuers-studium/...` (Missing forward slash after pipe)

Comment: Thanks, jen. I'm pretty sure I remembered the forward slash with the real subdomain, but it's always good to check. I've put the forward slash into my original post.

Comment: Universal analytics is going away in a couple months. Shouldn't you be working in GA4 at this point?

Comment: Yes, we should be. (However, we're not.)